# How to define attr that can show classname tips in layout file?

Tags: android

How to define attr that can show calssname tips in xml file like RecyclerView'attr 'app:layoutManger'? The attr will prompt me input the classname which extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager. After that, 'Cltr + click' will go to the java file. I wanna know how to do that!

[image: My image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to set the `layoutManager` from xml, you can do that following this

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" >
```

You can take a look at this [enter link description here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-dtt-13-how-to-set-recyclerviews-layoutmanager-in-xml-and-why-you-shouldn-t-350da048a801) for further informations.

Comment: It's a known this, and this is how you can set a `layoutManager` from xml, if it fits your needs please accept the answer, otherwise I will be happy to answer any further questions.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. You can find a link.